# SQL Query: Identifying Loan Non Starters and Finding Ten Payments made

Tags: sql, zoho

I need to identify a Customer who is NON-Starter of the Loan Schedule, Which means he did not pay the first EMI Schedule. and i need to know who are all paid 10 EMI Schedules and not Paid customers.

Note: This needs to be achieved with simple query statements. I can't use the PARTITION, OVER, LAG kind of Keywords. I can use UNION, JOIN, LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN.

For the First one, Non Starter Customer, I wrote a query like this but i suspect i am missing some records:

```
    SELECT  a.LoanID, 
            if(Case when a.SchedulePaymentDate  = b.TransactionDate AND a.DemandAmount - b.Collectionamount  = 0 then a.InstallmentNo end, 0, 1) as NonStarter 
   FROM  Schedule a 
     JOIN Collection b ON a.LoanID = b.LoanID AND   a.InstallmentNo  = 1
```

I am not sure if this is efficient or not, but what i am doing is, Checking the 1st Schedule date and collection date matching and Subtracting the Collection Amount from the Demand which should be zero then i am saying a flag 0 which Loan Starter otherwise the flag is 1 so he is a Non Starter of the loan.

For the 2nd One, HOw do we identify whether we have collected 10 EMI/Schedules? 
I am able to write the query for getting the summary value till 10 EMIs and the Date of the 10th EMI but i am not getting how to JOIN or apply a condition that these 10 EMI demand has been collected? I need to know both of the lOans with 10 Emis collected or not. EMI schedule will 18 to 24 Months usually.

Please give me the better approach not to miss any Loan whether a Loan Starter and non starter.

Table schemas given below:

```
Schedule: LoanID, PaymentDate, DemandAmount, InstallmentNo
Collection: LoanID, TransactionDate, CollectionAmount
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IF` in SQL). Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Its SQL Query language only i am using, but the Zoho Reports system accepts the IF condition, hence i used it. It is not Mysql, Oracle, SQL Server nothing, Just SQL query language it uses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Finding the Non-Starter done as follows:

Select LoanID, 
          if(SUM(CollectionAmount) = 0, 1, 0) NonStarter from Collection

From this i am able to identify the Non-Starters of Loans.

2. FOr 10 EMIs Paid:

   Select LoanID, if(SUM(Collection) = SUM(Demand),1,0) as DemandCollected from Demand Left JOIN Collection on Collection.Loand = Demand.Loanid and Demand.InstallmentNo < = 10

Hope this helps